# Extracting specific information from a cell in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, cell

I am just trying to get the ticker symbol from my cells, And my cells actually are in format of "stockexchange:ticker symbol", for example- NYSEARCA:VTI

> How can I refer to the cell with my stock exchange and ticker symbol, such that I only extract the ticker symbol in google sheets?

**Note:** the ticker symbol is always going to be after the symbol colon :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the data in column A

```
=index(if(len(A2:A), split(A2:A, ":"),),,2)
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "[^:]+$"),))
```

Note: depending on your locale, you may have to change the comma's to semi colons.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So I am trying to use it in conjunction with the formula for extracting the "annual dividend per share" and the formula is like this: =SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="&E9,"table", 9),7,2),"*","") where E9 is the cell with both stock exchange & ticker symbol! Do I need to make a separate column for extracting the ticker symbol or can i do the extraction within this formula?

Comment: Do you want the ticker symbol only in the formula? If so you could replace E9 (in your formula) with REGEXEXTRACT(E9, "[^:]+$") and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I only need it in the formula! Thanks again, that works perfectly :)